# Python: how to calculate the bucket points

Tags: python, nested-loops, buckets

```
import numpy as np
import math

length = 10

points = [(1,2,3),(1,1,1)，(23, 29, 0),(17, 0, 5)]

bucketed_points = {}

max_x = max([x for (x,y,z) in points])
max_y = max([y for (x,y,z) in points])
max_z = max([z for (x,y,z) in points])

x_buckets = int(max_x)/length + 1
y_buckets = int(max_y)/length + 1
z_buckets = int(max_z)/length + 1

for x in range(0, int(x_buckets)):

  for y in range(0, int(y_buckets)):

    for z in range(0, int(z_buckets)):

      bucketed_points["{0},{1},{2}".format(x, y, z)] = []

for point in points:
 # Here's where we actually put them in buckets
  x, y, z = point
  x, y, z = map(lambda a: int(math.floor(a/length)), [x, y, z])
  bucketed_points["{0},{1},{2}".format(x, y, z)].append(point)

print(bucketed_points)
```

I have four points (1,2,3), (1,1,1)，(23, 29, 0), (17, 0, 5), what I need to do is moving all the points to the new location (0,0,0), (0,0,0), (20,30,0), (20,0,10) which represent the center points for a cube whose side length equals 10 (length = 10).

Comment: Thank you for explaining what you need to do.  Do you have a question?

Comment: Your "question" is really vague. If you decide to make it clearer, make sure to mention what isn't working.

Comment: What my question is how can I move all the points to the center points mentioned above automatically using the looping structure?

Comment: What do you mean by "moving the points"? How do you "move" a point?